# Create a nested SQL loop

Tags: php, sql, loops, mysqli, nested-loops

How do I make a nested SQL loop using PHP?

I am trying to output all `bundle_id`'s from the table `packages` where the row `user` (primary key) is `$username`. Inside that loop, I want to run another loop to output `blacklist` from the table `access` where `bundle_id` (not primary key) is the output from the first loop.

Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT bundle_id FROM packages WHERE user='" . $username . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['bundle_id'];
    $sql = "SELECT blacklist FROM access WHERE bundle_id='" . $row['bundle_id'] . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo $row['blacklist'];
    }
}
```

The issue with my code is that it only outputs the first row from the table `access`.

Comment: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: @kerbholz When I change it, the page endlessly loads and eventually times out

Answer (score 3):

You're reusing the same local variable `$row` and `$result` in both loops, which is why you're not getting the correct results. But much better, use a `JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT a.blacklist
FROM access a
JOIN packages p ON a.bundle_id = p.bundle_id
WHERE p.user = ?
```

Notice, I'm using a bind variable to prevent SQL injection / syntax errors, etc.

Comment: How would I implement that in my script?

Comment: @ParsaYazdani: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php